How to get and set simple data or a variable in a session (Solid Start)?
I tried setting the username and then reading it in a session in the client side in the following code but it gives an error:
import { useSession } from "vinxi/http";

function getSession() {
  return useSession({
    password: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
  });
}

export default function Index() {
  const session = getSession();
  session.data.user = "adam"; //set the user name
  const username : string = session.data.user //get the user name
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Username: {username}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


"it gives an error" – what error?

To get a session value, you need to use the useSession function.
import { useSession } from "vinxi/http";

export async function getUser(): Promise<User | null> {
  const session = await useSession({
    password: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
  });
  const userId = session.data.userId;
  if (!userId) return null;
  return await store.getUser(userId);
}

You need to call session.update method to set a session value. It is an async function:
await session.update((d: UserSession) => (d.userId = user!.id));

Here is how it used with server functions:
export async function login(formData: FormData) {
  const username = String(formData.get("username"));
  const password = String(formData.get("password"));
  // do validation
  try {
    const session = await getSession();
    const user = await db.user.findUnique({ where: { username } });
    if (!user || password !== user.password) return new Error("Invalid login");
    await session.update((d: UserSession) => (d.userId = user!.id));
  } catch (err) {
    return err as Error;
  }
  throw redirect("/");
}


export async function logout() {
  const session = await getSession();
  await session.update((d: UserSession) => (d.userId = undefined));
  throw redirect("/login");
}

